# matplotlib deprecated() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'removal'

Tags: matplotlib, deprecated

I'm having trouble importing matplotlib.pyplot on Windows 10. I get the following error:

> matplotlib deprecated() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'removal'

That problem seems to have occured since I downgraded python from 3.7 to 3.6 (but I don't know if it is related).

Thanks!

Ien

Comment: Maybe you up- or downgraded matplotlib only partially? In that case reinstall matplotlib.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I reinstalled matplotlib. restart the python kernel (it was open in spyder) and it worked again.

Comment: Same here. My matplotlib didn't immediately start working right after its installation. Matplotlib started working after I restarted Spyder.

Answer (score 0):

In case both the options don't work, try uninstalling and reinstalling matplotlib and then launch Spyder from Anaconda Navigator. That should solve the problem